# Create a Monobehaviour using 'new' problem

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

so I have been following this tutorial to create a leaderboard system. Link below

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x0Wy7jQ7EFU&t=207s&ab_channel=EEDev

but I had problem on this following script

```
public class ScoreData : MonoBehaviour
{
    public List<Score> scores;

    public ScoreData()
    {
        scores = new List<Score>();
    }
}
```

the console said

"You are trying to create a MonoBehaviour using the 'new' keyword.  This is not allowed.  MonoBehaviours can only be added using AddComponent(). Alternatively, your script can inherit from ScriptableObject or no base class at all
UnityEngine.MonoBehaviour:.ctor ()"

the tutorial had no problem running but mine has. Hope to have some insight on the matter.

Comment: can you share Score class please

Comment: [Serializable]
public class Score : MonoBehaviour
{
    public string name;
    public float score;

    public Score(string name, float score)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.score = score;
    }
}

Comment: I change the ScoreUI script a to make user able to put their name in the board. but somehow it added multiple line. here are the script i changed imgur.com/tgRsUQL this is what happen after i update the score imgur.com/tOaARZ3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to remove  `: MonoBehaviour` from the class Score

Comment: yeah I just noticed it as well just now. thank you :D

but i had new problem where the score not showing on screen but im sure i had problem on some object not assigned properly much thanks.